# Reading from the Registry in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Library ( DLL ) that has a method with the following:

```
var masterKey =      
    Registry.
    LocalMachine.
    OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Dynamics\\5.0\\");
```

When running this method in an WinForms applicaiton, `masterKey` is not null and when running this in asp.net **`masterKey` is null**!

I've checked the executing user with `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` and the same user is executing both applications. The asp.net application is executed in visual studio ( debug: F5 ) and so is the WinForms application.

> How come I cannot read the key in
>   asp.net?

**Edit**

I've set the permissions to none what so ever and this gives me "Access Denied". And when I add the group Users I get `null`. Which would mean that I can fold up the strucutre and see that it's there, but I cannot access the keys/entried.

I am connected to a Domain, but this shouldn't affect my local instances of IIS, should it?

Comment: Have you set the appropriate permissions for the worker process?

Comment: The user has access to the registry key, what do I need to change in the process execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try granting to Network Service

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998320.aspx

The Network Service account does not have write access to the registry. If your application needs to write to the registry, you must configure the necessary access control lists (ACLs) on the required registry keys.

Comment: Load procmon and observe the key being accessed
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

Are you on a 64bit machine?

Comment: Yes it is a 64Bit Machine in VirtualBox.

Comment: Changing the user who runs the AppPool solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302406.aspx) (which is talking about encryption, but that's not the point):

> By default, the ASP.NET process identity used by the Web application will not have access to the registry. Access will need to be explicitly granted.

[This ASP.NET forums post](http://forums.asp.net/t/930599.aspx) describes how to set permissions (in this case for the Event log):

> Right click on the [relevant] key and select ... permissions...
>
> Add the account that asp.net is running in to the list. Select the account and make sure read and write is selected.

Comment: @Filip - I'm seaching at the moment.

Comment: @ChrisF, As I wrote in my question: `the same user is executing both application`. So It does have permissions, that's what's weird. I'll try add asp.net / iis aswell.

Comment: @Filip - The user is accessing the website, while the ASP.NET account is actually running the code.

Comment: I am talking about the Executing user, the application is not deployed to IIS and runs with the same user as the winforms application.

Comment: "@Filip - I'm seaching at the moment. " - just goes to show how active people are in SO to give a correct and complete solution.